# Could main function be suspended in Kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Kotlin coroutines and haven't worked with it before. Now I have a project that is making a heavy use of it and is a Spring Boot project. I noticed that the main function that bootstraps the SpringBootApp it self is marked as suspend, equivalent code below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class SomeClass

    fun main() {
        val someListener = SpringApplication
            .run(SomeClass::class.java)
            .getBean(AotherClass::class.java)

        while (true) {
            someListener.readSomething()
        }
    }
```

Of course, the `readSomething` function it self a suspend function that basically reads messages form some queue. My question is should the main func even be suspended because as far as I think it shouldn't and I should wrap the readSomething in `runBlocking` block but I'm not sure. The reason behind my hunch that it's wrong is because IntelliJ is not allowing the SpringBoot run configuration if I keep the suspend there.

Any explanation would be helpful here.

Comment: You can surround `while (true)` with a `runBlocking` and get pretty much the same effect as declaring `suspend fun main`, which is just a convenience for something very similar to `fun main() { runBlocking { ... } }`.

Comment: I know that I can get around it by using ```runBlocking { }``` that's why I was asking it should be like that, right? And don't decalre main as suspend it self.

Comment: I don't know any criteria by which it _should_ be like that, `suspend fun main()` is a completely legitimate thing in Kotlin. What Spring Boot assumes or allows is a separate question.

Comment: Okay, interestingly enough I can build and execute the project via command line but it's IntelliJ that doesn't allow any run configuration in this state.